# Combining 3 data frames based on common field 'Country'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 dataframes with a common index of Country. I need to combine each of the 3 based on that Country field.

My first try was to combine two and then the third and this is how far I got:

```
pd.merge(energy, GDP, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I have tried 3 options highly rated on this site:

```
import functools
dfs = [energy, GDP, ScimEn]
df_final = functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Country'), dfs)
```

```
energy.merge(GDP,on='Country').merge(ScimEn,on='Country')
```

```
pd.concat([energy.set_index('Country'), GDP.set_index('Country'), ScimEn.set_index('Country')], axis=1)
```

> KeyError: 'Country'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        40 #df_final = functools.reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Country'), dfs)
>        41 #energy.merge(GDP,on='Country').merge(ScimEn,on='Country')
>   ---> 42 pd.concat([energy.set_index('Country'), GDP.set_index('Country'), ScimEn.set_index('Country')], axis=1)

Comment: You should always include some sample of your data so that your error can be [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `pd.concat([x.set_index('Country') for x in dfs], axis=1)`?

Comment: Quang: I got the error 'str' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Answer (score 0):

You need to do multiple merges. Try the following:

```
merge1 = pd.merge(energy, GDP, how='inner', on='Country')
final = pd.merge(merge1, ScimEn, how='inner', on='Country')
```

Comment: I was suggested to share some of the data, so here it is:

Energy dataframe:
Country            Energy Supply    Energy Supply Per Capita    % Renewable
Afghanistan      321000000         10                                          78.6693

ScimEn dataframe:
Country        Rank   Documents  Citable Documents   Citations  Self Citations     
Afghanistan  163       3                               3                        49           0
GDP dataframe
Country              2006                                 2007  
Afghanistan       1.030523 X 10 +10           1.172119 X 10 +10

Comment: I keep getting an error on "KeyError: 'Country' - Maybe it's possible that the data types are not the same; I'll see if I can confirm. Thanks for trying